# Components moving when JTable Preferred Size Set Using MigLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, miglayout

I've been designing a Java application using the MigLayout layout manager but have run into an issue after setting the preferred size of a JTable. I would like to have the components on top of the JTable centred, which was the case before I set a preferred size for the JTable. The code concerning this part of the program is below:

```
 public MRGSCareersManagement(){
    super("") ;
    setLookAndFeel() ;

    GraphicsConfiguration config = this.getGraphicsConfiguration();
    Rectangle usableBounds = SunGraphicsEnvironment.getUsableBounds(config.getDevice());
    this.setMaximizedBounds(new Rectangle(0, 0, usableBounds.width, usableBounds.height));
    this.setExtendedState((this.getExtendedState() & this.MAXIMIZED_BOTH) == this.MAXIMIZED_BOTH ? JFrame.NORMAL : JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);

    this.setLayout(new MigLayout("align 50% 0%")) ;

    left = new JButton() ;  
    left.setIcon(new ImageIcon("src\\mrgscareersmanagement\\images\\leftImage.png"));
    left.setFocusPainted(false);
    left.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    left.setBackground(Color.white);
    left.addActionListener(this) ;

    right = new JButton() ;
    right.setIcon(new ImageIcon("src\\mrgscareersmanagement\\images\\rightImage.png"));
    right.setFocusPainted(false);
    right.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    right.setBackground(Color.white);
    right.addActionListener(this) ;


    header = new JLabel("Careers Management", SwingConstants.CENTER) ;
    header.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 35));
    header.setOpaque(true);
    header.setBackground(Color.pink) ;

    subHeader = new JLabel("", SwingConstants.CENTER) ;
    subHeader.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    subHeader.setOpaque(true);
    subHeader.setBackground(Color.pink) ;

    tableWidth = (int) (usableBounds.width * 0.7) ;
    tableHeight = (int) (usableBounds.height * 0.7) ;

    JTable table = new JTable(tableData, columnNames);
    JScrollPane tableScrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
    table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(tableWidth, tableHeight));
    table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    table.setShowGrid(true);
    table.setGridColor(Color.BLACK);
    table.setBackground(Color.pink) ;

    DefaultTableCellRenderer centerRenderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
    centerRenderer.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).setCellRenderer(centerRenderer);
    }

    this.getContentPane().setBackground( Color.white );

    this.add(left, "span 1 2") ;
    this.add(header, "align center") ;
    this.add(right, "span 1 2, wrap") ;
    this.add(subHeader, "align center, cell 1 1, wrap") ;
    this.add(tableScrollPane, "align center, span") ;

    setBackground(new Color(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f));
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE) ;
    setVisible(true) ;
    open() ;
}

private void setLookAndFeel() {  //Set UI manager
    try {  //Handle errors when setting UI manager
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(  //Set Nimbus as UI manager
                "com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel" 
        );
    } 
    catch(Exception exc) {   //Ignore Error
    }   
}
```

Currently the application looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7HHa.jpg

So how can I centre the content above the table (i.e. the header part and arrows)?

Thanks

Comment: So what is the issue that you run into? A exception or does it just not place  the header into centered?

Comment: The header isn't centered. Sorry, I will make that more obvious in the question

Comment: Have you tried to put the cell renderer in front of the resize operation? You´re code should work but maybe it´s some kind weird java bug that we experience from time to time^^ If that doesn´t work you should try to configure a JTable with a GUI designer (Netbeans for example) and see what it does differently.

Comment: So put .setPreferredScrollableViewportSize() after the DefaultTableCellRenderer and for loop?

Comment: Exactly. That is just an assumption of course but maybe the CellRenderer doesn´t allow a dynamic change of it´s properties

Comment: Not working unfortunately

Comment: Hm okay then I would advise to use a java GUI builder to find an alternate solution for this. You can always copy the code from that one to your program.

Comment: Ok thanks, will give that a go

Comment: `I would advise to use a java GUI builder to find an alternate solution for this.` - don't use a GUI builder. That won't help you learn Swing and the code won't be maintainable if you ever change IDE's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the default `BorderLayout` of the frame.

Add your JScrollPane containing the JTable to the frame using `BorderLayout.CENTER`.

Then create a "wrapper" panel to hold a child panel with the components you want centered and add this panel to the frame using `BorderLayout.PAGE_START`. The default layout of this panel is a FlowLayout with compoennts centered. So now all you need to do is create another panel with your "header" components and add this panel to the wrapper panel.

So the basic code is:

```
JPanel child = new JPanel( whatever layout manager you want );
child.add(...);
child.add(...);
JPanel wrapper = new JPanel();
wrapper.add( child );
frame.add(wrapper, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
```

Comment: Thanks, played around with your code and now it looks as I wanted it: https://imgur.com/gLGPdG9